# Python telegram bot - can the bot send the first message in chat?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Is it possible to get a bot to send the first message in the chat without running a command like "/Start"?

Maybe it possible to save the chat_id of the requested user in advance and send him a message in the future, thus allowing the bot to send a first message in chat according to a predefined condition that will trigger him?

I searched for an answer online but could not find one.
Can you send me a link to a tutorial that explains how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Yoav Giladi :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use a Telegram Bot [deeplink](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking-example) to provide an entry point to the Chatbot that does not require the users typing the `/Start` command.

After the very first interaction you can the obtain the `chat_id` which can be stored for using it to initiate a message later:

```
context.bot.send_message(chat_id, text='Howdy')
```